# Disable X-Button Icon on the top of the right in Messagebox Using C++ Win32 API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dialog

i am using C++ win32 API...

i have a Windows messagebox contain `OKCANCEL` Button...

the messagebox have a close(X-Button) on the right top...

`retun1=MessageBox(hDlg,TEXT("Your password will expired,you must change the password"),TEXT("Logon Message"),MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);`

i only want to close the messagebox using the `CANCEL` Button...

So,i want to disable the X-Button Icon...

i am already try `MB_ICONMASK` `MB_MODEMASK` Somethink like that.

But i cant get it,what i need...

How can i Resolve it?

Comment: The X button is a shortcut for Cancel. It's not clear why you want to disable the X if you still allow the user to click Cancel.

Comment: @RaymondChen, I agree. That's kind of what prompted the opening of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's most likely a bigger problem beyond what you've given us, but one way to disable the close button is to set the class style to include `CS_NOCLOSE`, which you can do with a window handle and `SetClassLongPtr`. Consider the following full example:

```
#include <windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI CreateMessageBox(void *) { //threaded so we can still work with it
    MessageBox(nullptr, "Message", "Title", MB_OKCANCEL);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, CreateMessageBox, nullptr, 0, nullptr);

    HWND msg;
    while (!(msg = FindWindow(nullptr, "Title"))); //The Ex version works well for you

    LONG_PTR style = GetWindowLongPtr(msg, GWL_STYLE); //get current style
    SetWindowLongPtr(msg, GWL_STYLE, style & ~WS_SYSMENU); //remove system menu 

    WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE); //view the effects until you close it
}
```

Comment: @ Chris :thank u ,but i am using Windows messagebox...i will try `CS_NOCLOSE` to that messagebox.but it not works... `retun1=MessageBox(hDlg,TEXT("Your password will expired,you must change the password"),TEXT("Logon Message"),MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);` ...i need this messagebox hide the X-close Button.

Comment: @SanjuMonu, I've updated my answer. You can choose to not give it a system menu, which effectively removes the close button altogether, rather than disabling it. This involves `SetWindowLongPtr`, as opposed to `SetClassLongPtr`.

Comment: @chris: You don't need to use a separate thread to find the message box's `HWND`. You can use `SetWindowHookEx()` instead to install a thread-specific `WH_CBT` hook that looks for the `HCBT_CREATEWND` notification.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, You could do that too. It's worth mentioning, but it doesn't fit into a short example that well.

Comment: @ Chris,@ Remy : I will use `MB_YESNO` instead of `MB_OKCANCEL`...`CS_NOCLOSE` is works fine...thank u for urs help...

Comment: Note that `CS_NOCLOSE` will affect *all* message boxes since it is a class style.

Comment: @RaymondChen, Very good point. I didn't think about that when I was writing the answer. I guess that's what spawns a lot of the behaviour I enjoy reading about.

Comment: FYI, Microsoft recommends calling ``SetWindowPos`` after calling ``SetWindowLongPtr``: ``Certain window data is cached, so changes you make using SetWindowLongPtr will not take effect until you call the SetWindowPos function.``

Answer (score 7):

In your OnInitDialog, you can try:

```
CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);

if (pSysMenu != NULL)
{
//disable the X
pSysMenu->EnableMenuItem (SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND|MF_GRAYED);
}
```

Comment: Not what the OP was asking, but exactly what I was looking for, so +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use `SetWindowsHookEx()` to install a thread-specific `WH_CBT` hook to obtain the MessageBox's `HWND`, then you can manipulate it any way you want.  For example:

```
HHOOK hHook = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK CBTHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND)
    {
        HWND hMsgBox = (HWND) wParam;
        LONG_PTR style = GetWindowLongPtr(hMsgBox, GWL_STYLE);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hMsgBox, GWL_STYLE, style & ~WS_SYSMENU);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int WarnAboutPasswordChange(HWND hDlg)
{
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, (HOOKPROC)CBTHookProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());

    int retun1 = MessageBox(hDlg, TEXT("Your password will expired, you must change the password"), TEXT("Logon Message"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

    if (hHook)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
        hHook = NULL;
    }

    return retun1;
}
```

On Windows Vista and later, there is another solution - use `TaskDialogIndirect()` instead of `MessageBox()`. Omitting the `TDF_ALLOW_DIALOG_CANCELLATION` flag from the `TASKDIALOGCONFIG.dwFlags` field will disable the X button, as well as the Escape key:

```
int WarnAboutPasswordChange(HWND hDlg)
{
    TASKDIALOGCONFIG config = {0};
    config.cbSize = sizeof(config);
    config.hwndParent = hDlg;
    config.dwCommonButtons = TDCBF_OK_BUTTON;
    config.pszWindowTitle = L"Logon Message";
    config.pszMainInstruction = L"Your password will expired, you must change the password";
    config.pszMainIcon = TD_INFORMATION_ICON;
    config.nDefaultButton = IDOK;

    int retun1 = 0;
    TaskDialogIndirect(&config, &retun1, NULL, NULL);

    return retun1;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I never knew about the Vista+ option. One nitpick: If you declare the callback properly, you shouldn't need to cast it in the call to `SetWindowsHookEx`.

Comment: So what is the value of hDlg parameter in `MessageBox`?

Comment: @java.begginer read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox).

Comment: use `SetWindowsHookEx` of course better than create separate thread. also possible use here `SetWinEventHook` for `EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE`. i only be check inside hook that `reinterpret_cast<CBT_CREATEWND*>(lParam)->lpcs->lpszClass == MAKEINTRESOURCE(32770)` or `GetClassLongW(hwnd, GCW_ATOM) == 32770` because not single window will be created

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this function:

```cpp
void DisableCloseButton(HWND hwnd)
{
    EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(hwnd, FALSE), SC_CLOSE,
        MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is significantly different from (or better than) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13189863/10871073), posted nearly 8 years ago?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).