# How can I make a window with a close button and no icon/menu to the top left of the window?

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I create a window that has menu buttons to the right such as the close button but without the icon to the left that opens a menu when you click on it.

EDIT: I've added a graphic example for clarity. [image: example]

Comment: What language are you wanting to use?

Comment: C++ (Characters required to allow comment)

Comment: You just can't.  You'll always get the system menu when you ask for the Close button.  There's little point in fighting the machine here, users expect a window to work this way.  If you insist on making it custom then create a borderless window with a close button that you draw yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the api reference for CreateWindowEx.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680(v=VS.85).aspx

If you have a window handle you can call SetWindowLong with a WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW flag which is like a single border style but smaller.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for, I want something similar to the messagebox style of window.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Are you trying to control the icon displayed in a messagebox or the border style of the window?

Comment: If you are trying to disable the system popup menu the look at SetWindowLongPtr(msg, GWL_STYLE, style & ~WS_SYSMENU); //remove system menu. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189791/disable-x-button-icon-on-the-top-of-the-right-in-messagebox-using-c-win32-api

Comment: @Itn I've added an example of what I'm asking for

Comment: I think you will need to use SetWindowLongPtr. Other than that, I can not think of a way to remove the system menu without creating a custom dialog.

Comment: @Itn last time i checked, removing WS_SYSMENU removes the close button as well, but I only did this by removing that flag during creation of the window, would using SetWindowLongPtr be different for some reason and only remove the icon and menu caused by sysmenu?

Comment: I have not used this option before so you would have to try it. The only other idea is to poll for the System menu message of your dialog and prevent the default action (Have not checked if this is possible).

Answer (score 0):

Just write when creating a window: WS_SYSMENU & ~WS_CAPTION